# CloudFront Signed URL : Access denied to "subfolders"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I've several objects on my S3 buckets "AwesomeBucket" :

- AwesomeBucket/Video/file.mp4
- AwesomeBucket/Audio/file.mp3
- AwesomeBucket/index.html
- AwesomeBucket/hello.html

From a single cloudfront signed URL i can access to `index.html` and `hello.html`(index.html actually includes hello.html) but i have a **403 access denied** from Video/ and Audio/ folders as `hello.html` attempts to access to `Video/` and `Audio/` resources.

Do you know how i can change the resource policy included in my signed url so `hello.html` can access to `Video/` and `Audio/` resources ?

Below is my actual Resource policy statement :

```
{ 
   "Statement": [
   { 
     "Resource":"http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/content/*", 
     "Condition":{ 
        "DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":1357034400}
      }
   }
  ] 
 }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution was to use CloudFront Signed Cookies to grant access to multiple files : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html

Comment: I am using signed urls. I can't access anything in a subfolder, but can access items in the root.